# "meals" in Apple docs on persistent storage urls... a folder or file?

Tags: ios, swift, url, storage

Within their documentation on storage, Apple uses URLS for file paths and, so far as I can tell, never gets explicit about what "meals" is within this context. And that's causing me no end of grief. Is "meals", in the following, a file or a folder?

Part way down [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html), is the following on the subject of a storage location:

> To create a file path to data
>
> In Meal.swift, below the //MARK: Properties section, add this code:

```
//MARK: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for:
 .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")
```

> You mark these constants with the static keyword, which means they
>   belong to the class instead of an instance of the class. Outside of
>   the Meal class, you’ll access the path using the syntax
>   Meal.ArchiveURL.path. There will only ever be one copy of these
>   properties, no matter how many instances of the Meal class you create.
>
> The DocumentsDirectory constant uses the file manager’s urls(for:in:)
>   method to look up the URL for your app’s documents directory. This is
>   a directory where your app can save data for the user. This method
>   returns an array of URLs, and the first parameter returns an optional
>   containing the first URL in the array. However, as long as the
>   enumerations are correct, the returned array should always contain
>   exactly one match. Therefore, it’s safe to force unwrap the optional.
>
> After determining the URL for the documents directory, you use this
>   URL to create the URL for your apps data. Here, you create the file
>   URL by appending meals to the end of the documents URL.

Comment: Meals is a file

Comment: @Paulw11 so I don't feel this stupid again (until the next time) how do I ascertain that from looking at this?

Comment: Well, all this code does is create a path, it depends on what is then done with the path, but in this case it will be used to create a pay as it says in the last sentence you quoted

Comment: So at the time of creation, "meals" could be either a file or a folder? It's only how it's later accessed that changes it to one or the other? @Paulw11

Comment: No, this code doesn't create a file or a directory. It creates a *path*. In some other code this path will be used to create a file.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but that's the nature of me. What's the path that's created? I'm guessing "DocumentsDirectory/meals/" but have no real idea how this is working, or what it's even doing. It seems... odd.

Comment: And, if that's the case, then "meals" is neither a file, nor a folder, but it's a component of a path, then that would make "meals" akin to, but not exactly like a folder?

Comment: @Paulw11 Perhaps I should be asking "how do paths work in URLS"? I don't know. This is VERY confusing, to me. How does everyone else conceive of what's happening here?